# Uncaught PDOException: fetch mode requires colno - but only on production server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been migrating a website from one server to another. The code is massive, so naturally I've had my share of problems. I believe they're all solved **except** for this persistent one:

On a particular page, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: fetch mode requires the colno argument' in /home/username/public_html/admin/lib/database.inc.php:59
```

The line referenced:

```
$myResult->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

I've been back and forth through the PDO documentation, so my diagnosis was originally that setting the fetch mode to PDO::FETCH_COLUMN required also setting a column number - no great deduction there. So I tried a value of 0 as the second argument. The page spent more than 30 seconds loading and got a PHP timeout. Same for a value of 1, and then I decided this wasn't the path to success.

Now, the really perplexing thing is that this site works perfectly on my local test machine without any modification, as well as on the original production server. I don't have easy access to the specs on the old server, but I know that those of my local test machine match those of the new server pretty damn closely.

Specifically:

Local PHP: 5.3.3

Remote PHP: 5.3.4

Local MySQL: 5.1.37

Remote MySQL: 5.0.91

Since I know the code is good *with some configuration*, I'm hoping someone knows the magic switch I can flip.

**--EDIT--**

Even with error_reporting set to E_ALL | E_STRICT on the local machine, this PDO exception doesn't appear.

Comment: `PDO::setFetchmode` requires a column number when specifying `FETCH_COLUMN`. The fact that it "works perfectly" on the other server may be a configuration problem (e.g.: error_reporting). It shouldn't: you are using a method outside its documented behavior. The problem is most probably lying somewhere else. I've tested this in 5.3.3 (with the proper arguments) with no issues whatsoever. What about the rest of the code? How big is your table on the remote server?

Comment: The table is <20,000 rows, and this code is only meant to fetch 40 rows at a time. Let me stress that **I didn't write this mess.** As such, I'm still trying to follow exactly how this thing works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Don't ask me why, but downgrading PHP to a particular version - as recommended by the original devs - did the trick. Nevermind that it was working fine locally with a more recent version. It just worked.

Answer (score -1):

Old question I know, but I was getting the same error and thought I'd post what I found. I solved it by using prepared statements and passing `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` to `fetchAll()`.

```php
$query = $database->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

I don't know why it works that and not with `$database->query()`. I don't need prepared statements here because I am not passing any parameters to the SQL, but it works so I roll with it. Hopefully that helps someone else who has this same error.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work with $database->query()?

Comment: No idea. I get the aforementioned error when I use `$database->query`, and I don't get the error when I use prepared statements. Best I can guess is a bug in PHP or PDO or something.

Comment: Can you provide the exact code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dominickj-tdi/22f9f2147e1cf54dc627b6a5cfa85ada

Comment: errr... I am at loss. Just curious, did you think about doing something like this `$query = $database->query($sql); $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);`?

Comment: No, I hadn't. I tried that just now, and that does work fine as well. Guess it's just `$database->query()` alone that doesn't work, although by my understanding of the docs it should.